# ¿Como cargar multiples html en un mismo div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, nodejs

necesito cargar varias veces un html dentro de otro html, lo estoy haciendo con JQuery con el metodo `$("#MiDiv").load("miSeccion.html")` pero esto sobre escribe mi div y necesito que se concatenen N numero de veces. este es mi codigo:

```
<li>
<div>
    <div>
        <label>Employer:_____________________________</label>
        <label>Dates: _______________________________</label>
        <label>Address:______________________________</label>
        <label>Supervisor:___________________________</label>
        <label>City,State,Zip Code:__________________</label>
        <label>Telephone:____________________________</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Were you subject to the Federal Motor Carrier Safety Regulations during this
            period?</label>
        <label>Yes______</label>
        <label>No______</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Were you subject to 49 CFR part 40 controlled substance and alcohol testing during
            this period?</label>
        <label>Yes______</label>
        <label>No______</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Reason for
            leaving________________________________________________________________</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function (){
        $("#List").load('EmployerHistorySection.html');
        $("#List").load('EmployerHistorySection.html');
    })
</script>
```

este es el div que quiero rellenar

```
    <div>
        <ol id = "List">

        </ol>
    </div>
```

Nota nueva: se puede usarse Nodejs para hacerlo?

Comment: weno se me ocurre que puedes cargarlos con un iframe asi pones una URL o el archivo HTML que quieres cargar...

Answer (score 1):

Dividamos tu problema en dos partes, primero, agregar varias veces un elemento de lista en una lista con un id.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  //asumimos que se leyo y se guardo en esta variable
  let employerHistory = `<li>
  <div>
    <div>
      <label>Employer:_____________________________</label>
      <label>Dates: _______________________________</label>
      <label>Address:______________________________</label>
      <label>Supervisor:___________________________</label>
      <label>City,State,Zip Code:__________________</label>
      <label>Telephone:____________________________</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Were you subject to the Federal Motor Carrier Safety Regulations during this
            period?</label>
      <label>Yes______</label>
      <label>No______</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Were you subject to 49 CFR part 40 controlled substance and alcohol testing during
            this period?</label>
      <label>Yes______</label>
      <label>No______</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Reason for
            leaving________________________________________________________________</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>`;
  $("#List").append( employerHistory );
  $("#List").append( employerHistory );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- seccion a llenar -->
<div>
  <ol id="List">

  </ol>
</div>
```

Como veras, usando `append` agregamos algo como un hijo del elemento seleccionado o de los elementos seleccionados.

Segundo, la lectura de tu pagina y cargarla en una variable se hace de manera asincrona, asi que el codigo que teniamos debera ir en la parte del `done`.

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
     url: "miSeccion.html",   
     async: false,
     success : function(text)
     {
         response= text;
     }
}).done(function(employerHistory) {
   $("#List").append( employerHistory );
   $("#List").append( employerHistory );
});
```